# Count occurrences of a substring in a string

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm trying to count the number of times a string, say `AAA` occurs in a longer string, say `AAAA`. The answer in this case is clearly 2:

- **AAA**A
- A**AAA**

None of these work as I would expect:

```
stringi::stri_count(str = "AAAA", regex = "AAA")
[1]

stringr::str_count(string = "AAAA", pattern = "AAA")
[1]

stringr::str_extract_all("AAAA", "AAA", simplify = T)
     [,1]
[1,] "AAA"
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is this a DNA? See this related post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40903331/680068 Using Biostrings library: `countPattern("AAA", DNAString("AAAA"))`

Comment: Yes it is but I'd prefer not to have to add another requirement (I'm already using tidyverse funs)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I match overlapping strings with regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20833295/how-can-i-match-overlapping-strings-with-regex)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a [look ahead positive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups) regex `(?=)` to count the occurrence of the substring like this:

```r
stringi::stri_count(str = "AAAA", regex = "(?=AAA)")
#> [1] 2
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer by [@Quinten](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77221972/12158757) directly solves your problem, cheers!

---

Here are two base R options, where `pat` is the pattern of substring, and `s` is the long string

```
lengths(gregexpr(sprintf("(?=%s)", pat), s, perl = TRUE))
```

or

```
sum(substring(s, 1:(nchar(s) - nchar(pat) + 1), nchar(pat):nchar(s)) == pat)
```